# Вызов функции с передачей параметров

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Забыл совсем, вылетело из головы.

Есть в JS вохможность вызвать функцию с передачей нэймспэйса и аргументов

```
func.apply(this, arguments)
```

Как сделать так же, только в PHP ?

Спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 call_user_func(__NAMESPACE__ .'\Foo::test');
```